# Remote yet central

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Dry lake messed up as a Lear (7)
> 2. Short Mervin found in summer vacation (4)
> 3. Probabilistic risk analysis conceals deep lake (6)
> 4. Historic city confounds a sand mark (9)
> 5. Fantasy prince's body of water stirred as a pie scan (10)
> 6. A sin reversed inside a Nissan (4)
> 7. Sulky ski confusing large lake (8)
> 8. Historic city hidden in Innsbruck hair parlour (7)
> 9. B in a dream twisted mountainous lakes (9)
> 10. Ski resort baffled shy UK lamb (9)

Where are we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
1   Dry lake messed up as a Lear (7)
```

> ARAL SEA (“as a Lear”, messed up. The Aral Sea is a lake which is currently losing water — the Eastern Basin of the lake is drying up.)

```
2   Short Mervin found in summer vacation (4)
```

> MERV (thanks, @NudgeNudge! It’s an ancient city in Turkmenistan, currently a UNESCO World Heritage Site.)

```
3   Probabilistic risk analysis conceals deep lake (6)
```

> proBAbilistIc risK anALysis hides BAIKAL. Lake BAIKAL is one of the deepest lakes in the world.

```
4   Historic city confounds a sand mark (9)
```

> SAMARKAND (thanks, @NudgeNudge! This is a historic city in Uzbekistan.)

```
5   Fantasy prince's body of water stirred as a pie scan (10)
```

> CASPIAN SEA (thanks, @NudgeNudge! One of the largest most distinctive bodies of water in Central Asia.)

```
6   A sin reversed inside a Nissan (4)
```

> NISA (“a sin”, reversed, it is inside NISsAn. Nisa, Turkmenistan is described as the first seat of central government of the Parthians).

```
7   Sulky ski confusing large lake (8)
```

> ISSYK-KUL (“sulky ski”, confused. Issyk-Kul is the 10th largest lake by volume in the world.)

```
8   Historic city hidden in Innsbruck hair parlour (7)
```

> innsBrUcK HAiR pArlour hides the historic city of BUKHARA, Uzbekistan.

```
9   B in a dream twisted mountainous lakes (9)
```

> BAND-E-AMIR (B in a dream, twisted. Band-e-Amir, Afghanistan is a national park with 6 lakes in the mountains.)

```
10  Ski resort baffled shy UK lamb (9)
```

> SHYMBULAK (shy UK lamb, baffled. Shymbulak is a ski resort in Kazakhstan.)

So as found by @NudgeNudge, we are in

> Remote locations of Central Asia!

Comment: Well done! I had found one or two more but you were faster than me :)

Comment: Thanks! Full credit to you @NudgeNudge — you did some great work!

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:

1. Dry lake messed up as a Lear (7)

> **Aral sea** 
> Aral sea is pretty dry these days
> Aral sea is an anagram of "as a Lear".

2. Short Mervin found in summer vacation

> **Merv** 
> Merv is short for Mervin
> Sum*MERV*acation.

4. Historic city confounds a sand mark (9)

> **Samarkand** 
> Samarkand is a historic city in current Turkmenistan
> Samarkand is an anagram of "as a pie scan".

5. Fantasy prince's body of water stirred as a pie scan (10)

> **Caspian sea** 
> Caspian is a prince from Chronicles of Narnia
> Caspian Sea is an anagram of "a sand mark".

6. A sin reversed inside a Nissan (4)

> **Nisa** 
> Nisa is "a sin" reversed
> You can find the letters of Nisa inside the word Nissan.

7. Sulky ski confusing large lake (8)

> **Issyk-Kul**
> Issyk-Kul is an anagram of "sulky ski"
> Issyk-Kul is a large lake in Kyrgyzstan.

9. B in a dream twisted mountainous lakes (9)

> **Band-e Amir**
> Band-e Amir is an anagram of "B in a dream"
> Band-e Amir is a national lake with lakes and natural dams.

10. Ski resort baffled shy UK lamb (9)

> **Shymbulak**
> Shymbulak is a ski resort in Kazakhstan
> Shymbulak is an anagram of "shy uk lamb".

So...

> Are we in **Central Asia** then?